# TYPO3 - News System teaser to META description

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Hi im working with the extension TS News (News System) in TYPO3.

My question is, if i have filled out the Teaser text field, how can i then say that the page META Description, is showing the Teaser text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is made in the extension template. Go to

`typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Detail/Opengraph.html`

there it is acutally integrated already (line 31,32)

that only works if the opengraph subpart is enabled in your detail view.

....of course you have to disable your corresponing header tags for the regular pages on the detail view page.

Don't change the original template otherwise an update will blow your changes!